# Unable to create build with Firebase plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, angular8, ionic5

I am trying to generate build with using [firebase plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase) with I am facing this issue during generating build.

[image]

I want to use phone authentication, and this plugin have a property for the phone authentication. there is also an FCM plugin but it doesn't have any phone authentication property.

I am using:

Ionic 5

Angular 8

Comment: Honestly rather use the firebase x plugin, the firebase plugin has not been updated for quite some time. Firebase X plugin is basically a maintained fork of the Firebase plugin

Comment: Have you tried removing the android platform, using the latest cordova-android and making a new build?

Comment: Yes it was working fine